# File download truncated if Response.Close() is called

Tags: c#, .net, download

Okay so i have page which bacially gets a file as a Byte[] from a webservice which I then give a Save/Cancel dialogue to the user to save that file. This file can either be xml or cvs format. When the file is downloaded the file is incomplete e.g. This is what the file should have:
USD,EUR,Euro,1.2,1.1,11/15/2009,15:23:27
USD,AUD,Australian,1.25,1.15,11/15/2009,15:23:27
but when saved from the browser it only has::
USD,EUR,Euro,1.2,1.1,11/15/2009,15:23:27
USD,AUD,Australian,1.25,1.

here is my code:

```
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName); 
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", MyFile.Length.ToString()); 
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(fileName); 
Response.ContentType = Utility.ReturnExtension(file.Extension.ToLower()); 
Response.BinaryWrite(MyFile); 
Response.Flush(); 
Response.Close(); 
Response.End();
```

I have already made sure the byte[] i am getting from webservice is okay by writing the file
on my machine using following code:

```
StreamWriter writer = null;
string blah = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(MyFile);
writer = File.CreateText(Server.MapPath(filePath+fileName));
writer.Write(blah);
writer.Close();
writer.Dispose();
```

If I remove the Close() and End() then the whole file is rendered with some HTML code from the page.
I get complete file(only XML format) if i first create/write file on my local machine and then do Response.TransmitFile(file).

I am not sure what i am doing wrong. Maybe its just something very simple. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Watch your download in Fiddler. See what error message, if any, is reported. RyanD's answer is probably the right one.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into a problem where a CSV file was being truncated in the response if I called `Response.Close()` after `Response.Flush()`.

My solution was to replace this:

```
 try
 {
      response.BinaryWrite(contentBuffer);
 }
 finally
 {
      response.Flush(); 
      response.Close();
 }
```

With this:

```
try
 {
      response.BinaryWrite(contentBuffer);
 }
 finally
 {
      response.End();
 }
```

`Response.End()` will flush all buffered content to the client. Try removing `Response.Close()` from your response handler.

Comment: That's correct, you should always use End() instead of Close(). I wrote about this here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/07/16/content-length-and-transfer-encoding-validation-in-ie10-download-manager-couldnt-be-downloaded-retry-cancel.aspx The short summary is that using Close() sends a TCP/IP RST to the client, which isn't what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", MyFile.Length.ToString());
```

And see if you get the full file when you do that. If you do, then you're getting a bad length from your file.

Comment: I did try removing the "Content-Lenght" but no luck. I also tried setting the length to higher than what it was getting but still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You might be filling up the Response buffer.  Try sending unbuffered, or if that doesn't work spread the file over several binarywrite calls and flush the buffer after each.

Comment: Tried sending it unbuffered but that didn't fix it. Haven't tried spreading the file over several binarywrite calls since it was such a small file.